# adding behavior when closing a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have created a JFrame and I would like to associate a specific behaviour when this JFrame is closed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`setDefaultCloseOperation`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) or add a [`WindowListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html).